# iTextSharp Font interfering with common font

Tags: c#, itext

I have included iTextSharp in my project to have an ability to create a PDF file.
This is my code for this:

```
Document document = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER,20,20,42,35);            
PdfWriter writer =
PdfWriter.GetInstance(document,newFileStream("Test.pdf",FileMode.Create));
document.Open();

Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Test");

document.Add(paragraph);

document.Close();
```

And now the error comes up saying: Font is an ambiguous reference between System.Drawing.Font and iTextSharp.text.Font.

This is the code which is red underlined:

```
RichTextBox tempBox = new RichTextBox();
tempBox.Size = new Size(650,60);
tempBox.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif,11.0F); //here is error
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(tempBox);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you have these `using` directives:

```
using System.Drawing;
using iTextSharp.text;
```

`Font` is in both namespaces, so it's indeed ambiguous.

You can fully qualify it, to resolve ambiguity:

```
using System.Drawing;
using iTextSharp.text;

// ...

tempBox.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif,11.0F);
```

Or you can specify an *alias*:

```
using System.Drawing;
using Font = System.Drawing.Font;
using iTextSharp.text;

// ...

tempBox.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif,11.0F);
```